# Components show animations only when the page is reloaded but not on state change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show three cards on the page at a time and I have applied transitions to those cards. When I click on the button it updates the state and shows another three cards. But those cards do not animate. Animations are working only when the page is reloaded and not on state change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shaw-pvku3

Comment: can you post with [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) link

Comment: Please show [mcve]

Comment: You probably implement a componentDidMount method but not a componentDidUpdate method. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to work. You sure its complete? I see nothing.

Comment: I have updated the code on codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a key to each `<Grow />` inside the map function.

React cannot discriminate each component that is rendered if you don't add the key to `<Grow />`. 
Without key on components, React think they are same component, and a new `<Grow />` will not re-animate.

I've attached codesandbox url below as an example.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-hooks-z75oc

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your state to the 'in' property of Grow

Grow in={this.state.updatedValue}

Hopefully this will solve your problem

To know more, check the docs for material UI
https://material-ui.com/components/transitions/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?